# Pin It Button not working for Tumblr Photosets

Tags: tumblr, pinterest

I am using this link code to add a Pin It button to my posts on a Tumblr page:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={Permalink}&media={PhotoURL-500}">
  Pin It
</a>
```

When I hit the pin it button on a single photo post, it pulls in the image and works correctly.  When you try to use the pin it button on a photoset post, it doesn't pull in any images from the photoset.

Does anyone have a solution to pull in the first image from the photoset?  Or a way to choose an image from the photoset?

You can preview my tumblr blog here: http://uncovet.tumblr.com/